# Google Sheets Apps Script : use checkbox to copy cell content to another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I would like to create a function to copy cell content, within the same sheet, from two columns (A & C) to columns E & G (respectively), if a checkbox in column D is checked.

Same question if it were instead for a range of columns (A-C) being copied to columns (E-G) with checkbox still in column D.

Thank you for your helpful and insightful solution(s).

Comment: All you need is a trigger onEdit() function with some script to copy the values.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

- You can try using this sample script below that uses the [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) method inside an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger with a condition to only copy when a checkbox on **column D** is selected.

### Sample Script

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  //Gets the Location where user cliks on the sheet
  var selection = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation().split("");
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  //Gets the checkbox value
  var checkBoxValue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();

  //Makes sure to run only when user selects any checkbox on column D
  if(selection[0] != "D") return; 

  switch(checkBoxValue){
    case checkBoxValue = "true":
      ss.getRange("A"+row).copyTo(ss.getRange("E"+row));
      ss.getRange("C"+row).copyTo(ss.getRange("G"+row));
      /* if you want to change it to copy a range of columns, use this instead:
  ss.getRange("A"+row+":C"+row).copyTo(ss.getRange("E"+row+":G"+row);
     */
      break;
  }
}
```

### Test Demonstration

> **Sample Sheet**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @irvinjayg ! I replicated your example and script on a new spreadsheet. It works flawlessly on rows 1-9, but any checkbox that is checked from row 10-onwards does not transfer the values over. I'm stumped...

Comment: Got you, had a little problem with row selection, updated my script and it will now work pass row 10 and up.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update your script, @irvinjayg. It does work perfectly now for any row but it seems that the trigger only works if it is located in columns A-Z (although it will effectively copy data located in any column to any other column). I found that if the trigger is located from column AA-onwards (which is my case), the script won't return any result.

Comment: Some additional details for you, @irvinjayg.  I found that if the trigger is located from column AA-onwards (which is my case), the script won't return any result. My exact scenario is : original data in col F & G, trigger in col AF, copy results in col AG & AH. Thank you so much.